# Create Azure AD Application Registration

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory

I'm building a C# desktop application that needs to connects to Azure Ressource Manager. The app must be independent from the Azure Portal.
I need to execute two PowerShell scripts file from C# to create an native application in Azure Active Directory.
the first scipt is :

```
Import-Module AzureRM.profile
Login-AzureRmAccount
```

The second is :

```
$pwd = "{service-principal-password}"
$secureStringPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $pwd -AsPlainText -Force

$azureAdApplication = New-AzureRmADApplication `
                        -DisplayName $appName `
                        -HomePage $appHomePage `
                        -IdentifierUris $appIdentifierUris `
                        -Password $secureStringPassword

New-AzureRmADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId $azureAdApplication.ApplicationId

New-AzureRmRoleAssignment -RoleDefinitionName Reader `
                          -ServicePrincipalName $azureAdApplication.ApplicationId.Guid
```

I have two pass $pwd, $appName, $appHomepage from C# code

Am I on the right way ?? need help

Answer (score 0):

You're getting close to it.

However, there are some tips for your scenario:

1. The scripts you posted are for [creating service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-authenticate-service-principal), not the whole steps for integrating your desktop app.

   You can use the `ApplicationId` in that command:`New-AzureRmRoleAssignment -RoleDefinitionName Reader -ServicePrincipalName $azureAdApplication.ApplicationId`
2. If you want to use powershell to integrate your app, you can refer to [these app creation scripts](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-desktop/tree/master/AppCreationScripts).

   - You can also refer to [this sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-desktop) to Integrate Azure AD into a Windows desktop application using interactive authentication.
   - For demonstrates a Desktop daemon application, you can refer to [this sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-desktop).

Both samples have the application creation powershell scripts.

Please let me know if this helps!